# Why am I getting a "uninitialized constant Feed::Feedzirra" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rss, feedzirra

I'm developing a ruby on rails -v 3.1.3 app that needs to pull a rss feed down. I've successfully installed feedzirra by adding it to my gemfile and running `bundle install`.

In my controller for the page that will display the rss feed I have

`@feed = Feed.new(blog_url_here)`

and I have a class named Feed.rb in my models folder that contains this:

```
def initialize(endpoint)
    atom = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse endpoint
    @atom = atom.is_a?(Feedzirra::Parser::Atom) ? atom : nil
end
```

When I load the page I get an "uninitialized constant Feed::Feedzirra" error. Anyone know  why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this could be caused by any number of different things. `@feed = Feed.new(blog_url_here)` Is this code within some method like `def new`?

Comment: Try adding `require 'feedzirra'` at the top of your Ruby Model

Comment: Also, you could be running into issues because your file is named Feed.rb and you are calling to a Class called Feed.. try renaming your model to something else

Comment: Ah, I see some more code would help. @garbagecollection, yes that line is within the index action on my BlogController.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz my Feed.rb defines the Feed class, i.e. class Feed
....
....
end. The initialize method is within this class. 

I had tried requiring feedzirra but that wasn't working for some reason. I eventually just chose to use something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help someone:

You should **restart** `rails server` after `bundle install`.